# Get scala-library.jar location

Tags: scala, jar, environment

How can I get the full path of scala-library.jar from file system with Scala code?
I've tried ways like `scala.Console.getClass.getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation.getPath` but it seemed don't work (returned a `null` pointer).

Answer (score 3):

We use this to adjust the classpath for caliper:

```
val so = classOf[ScalaObject].getResource("ScalaObject.class").toString
val scalaJar = so.substring(so.lastIndexOf(":") + 1, so.lastIndexOf("!"))
```

This works in eclipse and a fat-jar from command line under Mac OS and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to get it through the classpath like this:

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(java.io.File.pathSeparator)
  .filter{_.contains("scala-library")}.head
```

Comment: Thank you, I've found that our 2 methods work fine on command line but both fail on Eclipse with Scala plugin.

Answer (score 1):

A bit similar to the answer by thoredge, but also searches the boot classpath (this should work in Eclipse + ScalaPlugin):

```
List("java.class.path", "java.boot.class.path", "sun.boot.class.path")
  .flatMap(s => System.getProperty(s, "")
  .split(java.io.File.pathSeparator))
  .find(new java.io.File(_).getName == "scala-library.jar")
```